# Java: Starting a cmd process that won't execute his job, but loaded into memory

Tags: java, multithreading, process, cmd

My problem is: 
I want to start a process via a thread and that process should execute his job. As far as I started the process, he remains into memory and does *nothing* until I close my main program. (like it was some kind of suspended) 
And only after exiting main program, this process is starting to do what he must.

Did someone met that before?

Comment: Why would you want something loaded in memory if it does nothing?

Comment: Can you just start the thread when your main program exits?

Comment: I just want to make that process works and NOT to be idle while my program is running.

Answer (score 0):

The process is likely either waiting for input, or has filled its output buffer and needs you to empty it before it can continue. Take a look at `Process.getInputStream()`, `Process.getOutputStream()`, and `Process.getErrorStream()` for communicating with the process.

As a first step, you could try closing `Process.getOutputStream()` so it will stop waiting for you to provide input.